# Why is the real dependency different from the one listed in requirements.txt

Tags: python, requirements.txt

I've installed a package named xformers, here's its dependency tree

```
D:\Projects\Learning>pipdeptree -p xformers
xformers==0.0.23.post1
├── numpy [required: Any, installed: 1.26.2]
└── torch [required: ==2.1.2, installed: 2.1.2+cu121]
    ├── filelock [required: Any, installed: 3.13.1]
    ├── fsspec [required: Any, installed: 2024.2.0]
    ├── Jinja2 [required: Any, installed: 3.1.3]
    │   └── MarkupSafe [required: >=2.0, installed: 2.1.5]
    ├── networkx [required: Any, installed: 3.2.1]
    ├── sympy [required: Any, installed: 1.12]
    │   └── mpmath [required: >=0.19, installed: 1.3.0]
    └── typing_extensions [required: Any, installed: 4.10.0]
```

which shows its denpendency is `torch==2.1.2`

but the [requirements.txt](https://github.com/facebookresearch/xformers/blob/v0.0.23.post1/requirements.txt)  declares a lower version

```
torch >= 1.12
numpy
```

and [setup.py](https://github.com/facebookresearch/xformers/blob/v0.0.23.post1/setup.py) just reads the `requirements.txt` (line 403), seems nothing else special.

then, how does it work?

the img below is a similar case with xformers==0.0.24 and torch==2.1.2, if it helps

[showcase](https://i.stack.imgur.com/KEaYN.png)

Comment: Did you try to read the documentation for `pipdeptree`? It isn't a built-in tool, so only knowing about Python won't be enough to answer the question.

Comment: Simply put : xformers requires a version of torch greater or equal to 1.12. The way pip deals with this is by choosing the latest version matching the constraint, which in this case appears to be 2.1.2 (the latest version I guess)

Answer (score 0):

When dealing with package dependencies in Python, especially when using pip and a requirements.txt file, the specified requirements serve as a baseline for compatibility. This means that the packages listed in requirements.txt are the minimum versions required for the software to run properly.

The process of determining which version of a dependency to install is based on resolving all the version constraints specified in the requirements.txt files of all installed packages. pip attempts to find a set of versions that satisfies all the constraints.

Comment: Well, in my case, torch is required by no package else but xformers ( according to the result of "pipe show" ), and xformers requires torch and numpy (and numpy doesn't require torch, means it can do nothing about torch's version ). So, the installed version already meets the only requirement, why it choose to install a higher version?